# AttributeError al usar .iteritems

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me encuentro con el error AttributeError y no se por que

estoy haciendo un menu interactivo en el cual uso iteritems, alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar esto o darme una mejor opcion?

```
def funcion_uno():
  print('Esta es la funcion uno')

def funcion_dos():
  print('esta es la funcion dos')




if __name__ == '__main__':
  salir = False
  print('\033[1;32;40m Menu interactivo de Daft Punk')
  
  mensaje = 'Ingrese la opcion deseada: '
 
  menu = { 'a)': funcion_uno , 'b)': funcion_dos }
 
  while not salir:
    print('-'*len(mensaje))
    print(mensaje)

    for opcion, funcion in menu.iteritems():
      print(opcion) 

    respuesta = raw_input('\nOpcion: ').lower()
    salir = respueta == 'exit()'
  else:
    print('Hasta luego')
```

Comment: Seguramente estás usando Python 3. Ya `iteritems()` no existe. Usa `items()`.

Comment: Buenisimo, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estás en python3, usa dict.items() en lugar de dict.iteritems()

iteritems() se eliminó en python3, por lo que ya no puede usar este método.

Cambia esta linea

```
for opcion, funcion in menu.iteritems():
```

a

```
for opcion, funcion in menu.items():
```

Comment: Mas adelante en el codigo me sale otro problema. funcion = menu.get(respuesta, None)
   if funcion: 
     funcion()          me dice Indentation error, sabes por que puede pasar esto?

Comment: Revisa la sangría del código, probablemente algo no esta ordenado, python reconoce los bloques de código a través de la sangría (normalmente 2-3 espacios) asegúrate que todo esta ordenado, con los espacios correspondientes y debería funcionar; Ejecute tu código y todo salio bien en mi pc.

Comment: @Nedreus Usa algun editor que soporte python como  VSCode para evitar los problemas triviales como la indentación.